# Sending data to app.delete in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am trying to delete a certain input from my database. I cant seem to get the data to come through on an `app.delete` to know which entry to delete. However `app.post` gets the data. Here is my code

Client:

```
let userToDelete = {
    data:entryToDelete
}

httpRequest.delete(url, userToDelete)
    .then(function (response) {
        //...
```

Server

```
app.delete('/api/deleteEntry', function(req, res){
    console.log('going to delete', req.body);
    //...
});
```

now if I change to `httpRequest.post` and `app.post`, `req.body` console logs the data I send. Does a `.delete` request not get the data?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[RFC2616](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec9.html) says:

> The DELETE method requests that the origin server delete the resource
>   identified by the Request-URI.

Request bodies are not explicitly disallowed for HTTP DELETE requests, but I wouldn't rely on them always being available.  You'll have to include some sort of ID or primary key in your request URI, so that your server can pass that along to your database for deletion.

Comment: Thanks! I am decently new to node. Where I work we are a Java shop and I do primarily front end. Though we are implementing node now. I didnt realize this is how the java servers also do it. They pull a key from the request uri. We dont send data to a .delete. Thanks!